# Replace Last Occurrence of Substring in String (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching, substring, variable-expansion

From the bash software manual:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a
>   pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the
>   longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.
>   ... If pattern begins with ‘`%`’, it must match
>   at the end of the expanded value of parameter.

And so I've tried:

```
local new_name=${file/%old/new}
```

Where string is an absolute file path (`/abc/defg/hij` and `old` and `new` are variable strings.

However this seems to be trying to match the literal `%sb1`.

What is the syntax for this?

### Expected Output:

Given

```
old=sb1
new=sb2
```

Then

`/foo/sb1/foo/bar/sb1` should become `/foo/sb1/foo/bar/sb2`

`/foo/foosb1other/foo/bar/foosb1bar` should become `/foo/foosb1other/foo/bar/foosb2bar`

Comment: @anubhava quickly changed the requirements there as I realized what I really needed, though it would be useful for it to work with literals too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only shell-builtin [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
src=sb1; dest=sb2
old=/foo/foosb1other/foo/bar/foosb1bar

if [[ $old = *"$src"* ]]; then
  prefix=${old%"$src"*}                  # Extract content before the last instance
  suffix=${old#"$prefix"}                # Extract content *after* our prefix
  new=${prefix}${suffix/"$src"/"$dest"}  # Append unmodified prefix w/ suffix w/ replacement
else
  new=$old
fi

declare -p new >&2
```

...properly emits:

```
declare -- new="/foo/foosb1other/foo/bar/foosb2bar"
```